# Scaling only one axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis, figure

Using this command, `axis([XMIN XMAX YMIN YMAX]` we can set range of both x and y axis.

Is there any way by which only one particular axis of plot is scaled while other is set at auto-scaling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`xlim`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html), [`ylim`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) and [`zlim`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zlim.html) for manually setting the limits of every axis.

For example:

```
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = sin(x);

plot(x,y);
XMIN = 0;
XMAX = pi;
xlim([XMIN XMAX]);
```

This is the output:

[image: sin(x) with x from 0 to pi]